# Control the visibility of images inside branch indicator

Tags: qt, qml

On a tree view, I observe this behavior of branch indicator:

[image: Branch indicator behavior]

I intend to control the visibility of my branch indicator images regardless of having children. How can I do that?

I'm setting the visibilities on my [TreeViewStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-treeviewstyle.html) but they are NOT taking effect:

```
TreeView {
    ...
    style: TreeViewStyle {
        indentation: 25
        branchDelegate: Item {
            visible: true // ** visible
            width: 20
            height: 10
            Image {
                // I want this image to be visible only if item has children:
                visible: styleData.hasChildren
                width: 10
                height: 10
                ...
                source: "images/arrow.png"
                transform: Rotation {
                    origin.x: 10 / 2
                    origin.y: 10 / 2
                    angle: styleData.isExpanded ? 0 : -90
                }
            }
            Image {
                // I want this image to be always visible:
                visible: true
                width: 10
                height: 10
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    ...
}
```